# How to update particular server files (or) partial deployment in amazon elastic Beanstack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a new version in amazon elastic beanstalk with .ebextension folder. But I have only see new deployment version files in website and lost the old files which was present in old version. How to update particular server files  (or) partial deployment in amazon elastic beanstalk ?

Comment: Can you go into more detail what you mean by this: "But I have only see new deployment version files in website and lost the old files which was present in old version."? Are you making changes to files on the server outside of the deployment process?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot partially update deployments in Elastic Beanstalk. The application zip bundle you upload during a deployment entirely replaces the old bundle.

If you want to "partially update" files in a deployment, merge the changes on the machine from which you are deploying, then zip the merged bundle, then deploy the new application version.